# htaccess Does Not Re-write Properly with Parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I am converting the old site which has pages with the following parameters:

```
oldpage.cfm?c=xxx&p=yyy  
oldpage.cfm?c=xxx&cpage=yyy  
oldpage.cfm?c=xxx&i=yyy
```

I want it so that all these will go to /newfolder/xxx with the the re-write

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.cfm?c=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?&(p|cpage|i)=(A-Za-z0-9)$ /newfolder/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

but it's not doing the re-write.  I have re-write rules right after that which will take /newfolder/$1 and change to newpage.htm?c=$1

```
RewriteRule ^newfolder/([A-Za-z0-9-_\s]+)/?$ newpage.htm?c=$1 [NC]
```

This one is working if user comes in with /newfolder/xxx

Can't figure out what is wrong with the first rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule doesn't "see" the query string. It only sees the requested URI. To do things with the query string, you need to augment the rule with a RewriteCond. See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString for a detailed treatment of this topic.

In particular, you'll want to do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/path /path/%1/%2?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redirect rule in addition to your new rule for `newfolder/...`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)c=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.cfm$ /newfolder/%1? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^newfolder/([\w\s-]+)/?$ newpage.htm?c=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: @anubhave I have whole bunch other rewriterule after that, do I need to put the "L" in the [NC,L,QSA}?  I try to other page rewrite like Redirect 301 /oldpage1.htm http://www.sample.com/newpage1.htm  Redirect 301 /oldpage2.htm http://www.sample.com/newpage2.htm etc. one follow the other but they don't seem to work

Comment: Yes, you will need `L` flag. Keep `301` rules before other rules. But you should show your current .htaccess in question so that I can examine and suggest accordingly.